# Runaway argument? error with springer template

Tags: affiliation, springernature

Why did I get this error, "Runaway argument?"

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
  \begin{document}
    
    \title{Insert your title here%\thanks{Grants or other notes
    %about the article that should go on the front page should be
    %placed here. General acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.}
    }
    \subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}
    
    %\titlerunning{Short form of title}        % if too long for running head
    
    \author{First Author         \and
            Second Author %etc.
    }
    
    \institute{ \at
                   $^{1}$ first address \\
                  
                  %\email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
    %             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
               \and
                \at
                    $^{2}$second address
    }
    
    \date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
    % The correct dates will be entered by the editor
    
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
    \keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
    % \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
    % \subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
    \end{abstract}
    \end{document}
    % end of file template.tex
```

Update: How to remove the space between the two lines?

[image]

Comment: No, the same error!

Comment: I update the question

Comment: I added the \documentclass

Comment: removing the blank lines makes the example run without error

Comment: Where ? please?

Comment: the error message shows the line, but see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is complaining about misplaced `\par` (blank lines). This runs without error.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
  \begin{document}
    
    \title{Insert your title here%\thanks{Grants or other notes
    %about the article that should go on the front page should be
    %placed here. General acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.}
    }
    \subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}
    
    %\titlerunning{Short form of title}        % if too long for running head
    
    \author{First Author         \and
            Second Author %etc.
    }
    
    \institute{ \at
                   $^{1}$ first address \\
                  %\email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
    %             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
               \and
                \at
                    $^{2}$second address
    }
    
    \date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
    % The correct dates will be entered by the editor
    
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
    \keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
    % \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
    % \subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
    \end{abstract}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, How to remove the space between the two lines?

Comment: @ayla the space in the input? just delete it in your editor. The spacing of the output is chosen by Springer, don't change it.

Comment: I mean of the output, between first address and the second address. Ok thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ayla remove the `\\ ` after the first author address (the second address is on a new line anyway, so that is just forcing space)